# Django 1.11 - python 3.4 // not able to createsuperuser

Tags: django-1.11

**(geoenv) C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\Mtech Project\Stage 8 database start\geosite>python manage.py createsuperuser
You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 96, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management__init__.py", line 148, in get_default_username
    auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in **len**
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1105, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in **iter**
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 886, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 876, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in **exit**
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\MTECHP~1\STAGE8~1\geoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

**django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user**

Answer (score 1):

createsuperuser 
cmd can only be used after making models and makemigrations and migrate cmd.
I was trying to use it before that.